# ZK Framework : Refresh dynamic Layout using foreach

Tags: jakarta-ee, foreach, zk

I'm using forEach "myList" to draw elements. Now, when I update data in "myList", my page can not redraw.
I tried use invalidate() but not OK.
Please help me.
Thanks very much.

My code below :

```
<vlayout id="mainLayout" >
        <groupbox hflex="1" mold="3d" open="${forEachStatus.index==0}" forEach="${vm.myList}">
            <caption label="${each.groupName}" sclass="customIcon">
                <span id="arrow-${forEachStatus.index}" class="open-${forEachStatus.index}" />
            </caption>
            <vlayout hflex="1" spacing="10px">
                <groupbox hflex="1" mold="3d" forEach="${each.listData}" open="false">
                    <caption label="${each.groupName}" sclass="customIcon">
                    </caption>

                    <listbox emptyMessage="Empty data" mold="paging" pageSize="10"
                             sizedByContent="true" hflex="1">
                        <!--Listbox content here-->
                    </listbox>

                </groupbox>
            </vlayout>



        </groupbox>
    </vlayout>
```

ViewModel

```
 @Command("onSearch")
@NotifyChange("myList")
public void onSearch() {
    try {
        //Business OK here, reload myList OK
        if(mainLayout!=null){
            mainLayout.invalidate();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the full code (or at least more of it) it is hard to help. It looks like you are using MVC and MVVM. I recommend sticking to MVVM. Specifically [this](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/data_binding/collection_and_selection.html) might be useful.

Use `children` in your `vlayout` to iterate over your `myList` elements:

```
<vlayout children="@load(vm.myList)">
    <template name="children">
        <groupbox hflex="1" mold="3d" open="@load(each.index eq 0)">
            <!-- contents of groupbox here -->
        </groupbox>
    </template>
</vlayout>
```

In your `onSearch()` method you don't need to invalidate `mainLayout`. The `@NotifyChange("myList")` should reload your `myList` (provided you have a getter method in your ViewModel class)